# Combining for loop and mutate within a function for multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I'm hoping I can get some insight into my problem. Basically, I want to create the same set of variables within several different data sets (they are subsets of the original dataset based on outliers, protest answers, etc.). I have tried many things, but I'm completely stumped.

Firstly I realize that using eval(parse( is against suggestions however, I am not the most efficient coder and this was working for my purposes. 
Anyway, my aim is basically to create a set of variables - X_3, X_4, X_5, etc. which is the year amount (x12) of a set of other variables - z1_1, z2_1, z3_1, etc. 
for this, I have the below code, which works when I individually put in each dataset name where 'data' is.

Edit:
Data expectiations

```
#what it looks like now
  responseid   z3_1 z4_1 z5_1
1          1  4.720 7.08   NA
2          2  1.180   NA 1.18
3          3  1.180   NA 1.18
4          4  2.596 3.54   NA
5          5 15.340   NA   NA
6          6  2.360   NA 2.36

#what i'd like it look like:
  responseid   z3_1 z4_1 z5_1    X_3  X_4  X_5
1          1  4.720 7.08   NA  56.640 84.96    NA
2          2  1.180   NA 1.18  14.160    NA 14.16
3          3  1.180   NA 1.18  14.160    NA 14.16
4          4  2.596 3.54   NA  31.152 42.48    NA
5          5 15.340   NA   NA 184.080    NA    NA
6          6  2.360   NA 2.36  28.320    NA 28.32

#dput
#original
structure(list(responseid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L), z3_1 = c(4.72, 1.18, 1.18, 2.596, 15.34, 2.36), z4_1 = c(7.08, 
NA, NA, 3.54, NA, NA), z5_1 = c(NA, 1.18, 1.18, NA, NA, 2.36),  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))

#expected
structure(list(responseid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L), z3_1 = c(4.72, 1.18, 1.18, 2.596, 15.34, 2.36), z4_1 = c(7.08, 
NA, NA, 3.54, NA, NA), z5_1 = c(NA, 1.18, 1.18, NA, NA, 2.36), 
    X_3 = c(56.64, 14.16, 14.16, 31.152, 184.08, 28.32), X_4 = c(84.96, 
    NA, NA, 42.48, NA, NA), X_5 = c(NA, 14.16, 14.16, NA, NA, 
    28.32)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 6L))
```

But I'd like to do this for several datasets, hence why I'm looking to use a function to run across each df.

```
for (i in 3:9){
    X.varname <- paste0("X_",i)
    data <- data %>%
      mutate(
        !!X.varname := eval(parse(text=paste0("z", i, "_1")))*12
      )
  }
```

However, when I try to put this in a function (so I can run it over a list of data frames) nothing happens:

```
f.test <- function(data){
for (i in 3:9){
    X.varname <- paste0("X_",i)
    data <- data %>%
      mutate(
        !!X.varname := eval(parse(text=paste0("z", i, "_1")))*12
      )
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?
This is my first question on StackOverflow so I apologize if any of the formatting is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @Meg, welcome to StackOverflow, could you please provide a clearer example of what you are trying to do? A simplified version of you dataframe (use `dput(data)`) and an expected output.

Comment: Thnks, I've done this now!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens because the function does not return anything.  Usually you don't need to explicitly `return` something in R, because R automatically returns the last object. But this being a for loop, means it returns nothing.

To avoid the problem simply specify what your function should return ie. `data`:

```
f.test <- function(data){
  for (i in 3:5){
    X.varname <- paste0("X_",i)
    data <- data %>%
      mutate(
        !!X.varname := eval(parse(text=paste0("z", i, "_1")))*12
      )
  }
  return(data)
}
```

By the way, you are right that `eval(parse(x))` is not suggested because it's  dangerous and slow.

Not sure if what you showed us is really what you are trying to do, but a better way to do it would be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)


my_fun <- function(data) {
  data %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("z")), .funs = list(TBC=~.*12)) %>% 
    rename_at(vars(ends_with('TBC')), .funs = ~{.x %>% str_extract('\\d') %>% str_c('X_', .)})
}
```

More over, as you need to do this to multiple dataframes you could use @koenniem suggestion to use `purrr::map()`. Put every dataframe in a list and apply the function to eache element of the list:

```
library(purrr)
df2 <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(-responseid), ~.+4)

df_t <- list(df, df2)

df_t %>% 
  map_df(my_fun)
#>    responseid   z3_1  z4_1 z5_1     X_3    X_4   X_5
#> 1           1  4.720  7.08   NA  56.640  84.96    NA
#> 2           2  1.180    NA 1.18  14.160     NA 14.16
#> 3           3  1.180    NA 1.18  14.160     NA 14.16
#> 4           4  2.596  3.54   NA  31.152  42.48    NA
#> 5           5 15.340    NA   NA 184.080     NA    NA
#> 6           6  2.360    NA 2.36  28.320     NA 28.32
#> 7           1  8.720 11.08   NA 104.640 132.96    NA
#> 8           2  5.180    NA 5.18  62.160     NA 62.16
#> 9           3  5.180    NA 5.18  62.160     NA 62.16
#> 10          4  6.596  7.54   NA  79.152  90.48    NA
#> 11          5 19.340    NA   NA 232.080     NA    NA
#> 12          6  6.360    NA 6.36  76.320     NA 76.32
```

Comment: I'd try `data[[X.varname]] <- data %>% transmute( !!X.varname := eval(parse(text=paste0("z", i, "_1")))*12)` in `f.test`. Nice wrok with `str_*`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens because you assign `data` to the `data` argument to the function, which is a different `data` from the one in your global environment. You can use `assign(data, YourAssignedValue, envir = .GlobalEnv)` or use the deep assign operation `<<-`. Alternatively, since you want to replace the original data, simply return `data` like so:

```
f.test <- function(data){
    for (i in 3:5){
        X.varname <- paste0("X_",i)
        data <- data %>%
            mutate(!!X.varname := eval(parse(text=paste0("z", i, "_1")))*12)
    }
    data
}
data <- f.test(data)
```

If I may suggest another approach; You could make a nested tibble data sets using, for example, `tibble::tribble` and then performing mutations etc. using `purrr::map`.

Comment: so i tried this, but using GlobalEnvir and assign just leads to variables outside of the dataframe, which isn't helpful when I need to create the same variables in like 5 dataframes...

Comment: I see what you want to do now. I've updated my answer.